# ReferenceError: Can't Find Variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

So i'm new to React Native but every time i put a new Component like a Button or an Image from Facebooks React Native Doc's i keep getting a "ReferenceError : Can't Find Variable" error on the simulator? This honestly happens when i add any other piece of code other than Text. Am i not linking something incorrectly? Anything would help.

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          This is a new App!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
        <Button
  onPress={onPressLearnMore}
  title="Learn More"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
        <Text style={{color: 'blue'}}>Hello</Text>
      </View>
        
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

**ERROR
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE5Pv.png)

Comment: Text and View were imported from react-native, why hasn't Button been imported from anywhere?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but does every component have to be listed under the import list?

Comment: No worries, yeah, everything you want to use in a given file needs to either be imported from somewhere else or declared somehow before it is used.

Comment: Oh i see, yeah it's starting to work now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `Button` to the import like so:

```
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Touchable Opacity instead of button, Its very efficient way inside that you can add Text and also the on click functions too.....

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { KeyCheck() }}>
    <LinearGradient useAngle={true} angle={45} angleCenter={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
        colors={['#1ac6ff', '#00ace6', '#0083b0']}
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
        style={styles.submitbtn}>
            <Text style={[styles.starttxt, { fontSize: Commonwidth(15), alignSelf: "center" }]}>
                    {"Submit"}
            </Text>
    </LinearGradient>
</TouchableOpacity>`
```