# ReactNativeJS: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: View

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have just started react-native and trying to create first Hello, world screen but I'm getting below error

```
ReactNativeJS: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: View

    This error is located at:
        in Unknown
        in RCTView
        in RCTView
        in c
```

below is my code for `App.js`

```
import React, {Fragment,Component} from 'react';

import HelloWorldApp from './components/HelloWorldApp';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/' component={HelloWorldApp} />
       </div>
      </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Below is my code for `HelloWorldApp.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have already import this `import {Text, View} from 'react-native';` but still I'm getting error `Can't find variable: View`

Below are some links that i have already check but it didn't help me to solve my issue

- [Can't find Variable : "View"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642567/cant-find-variable-view)
- [Can't find variable: React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685849/cant-find-variable-react)
- [ReferenceError: Can't Find Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231429/referenceerror-cant-find-variable?rq=1)

**UPDATE**

> I have tried this `Delete and re-install the node modules`

Now I'm getting this error

```
ReactNativeJS: Error: Invariant failed

    This error is located at:
        in l
        in f
        in RCTView
        in RCTView
        in c
```

can anybody tell me what I'm missing

Can anybody help me to solve this issue

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: If this suddenly happens have you try to close all files and rerun them again? I had  situations that fixed by rerunning

Comment: @behzad thanks for the quick replay let me check this

Comment: @behzad sorry to say but getting same issue again

Comment: Sorry to hear, if this is first time you are running , it may be other things (like not installing dependencies ) but if this happened out of blue that was the only thing that I can think of, few times I had strange error like yours, and when I closed all programs and run them again, it fixed. By the way I hope you find a way to fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

Might be some issues while loading.

Do one thing :

> Close the packager and restart the packager along with closing and deleting the
>   app and reinstalling it.

**OR**

> Delete and re-install the node modules

`App.js`

```
import React, {Fragment,Component} from 'react';

import HelloWorldApp from './components/HelloWorldApp';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>

          <Route exact path='/' component={HelloWorldApp} />

      </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks i have tried this `deleting the app and reinstalling it.` but it didn't help me, can you please explain more about this `Delete and re-install the node modules` solution

Comment: delete the node modules folder from root. And then do `npm install`. Have you tried closing the packager.

Comment: *Have you tried closing the packager* how to close `packager`

Comment: i have tried `Delete and re-install the node modules` now I'm getting this error `ReactNativeJS: Error: Invariant failed This error is located at:` check updated question

Comment: The terminal which opens or the starter which opens when you run a react project which bundles your file.

Comment: Try deleting the node modules folder and then re installing them

Comment: share app.js file too

Comment: please check updated question i have added `app.js` file

Comment: Updated the answer check now. Why have you used div?

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem in your code.you should only try react-native init example again and enjoy on another directory

Comment: [`react-native init` This package has been deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-init)

Answer (score 0):

import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

render(){
    return (
      
        Hello world!!
      
    )
  }
}

1.Create new react native project
2.Delete App.js code
3.And paste this code in App.js
4.run.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

   render(){
        return(
          <View>
               <Text>Hello world</Text>
          </View>
          )
    }
}
```

1. Create new project
2. Delete App.js code
3. and paste this code in App.js
4. run